# Expected number of days that we see something rarely happen

Tags: probability, expected-value

We are given the following information.

There are 1 million phone users, out of which 100 have Windows phone.

You have a website which is visited by exactly 10000 independent users every day.

Now, the question is what is the expected number of days per year that we see 3 or more Windows users come to our website?

**My attempt:-**

I am trying to first think in terms of the probability of getting 3 or more Window users in 1 day.

So $P(E) = 1- P(E_0) - P(E_1) - P(E_2)$
where $P_I$ = Probability of seeing "I" windows users in a day.

I end up with a very complicated equation that I cannot resolve. On top of that, I cannot related back to calculate expected number of days.

Please advise. I am really struggling with this.

Comment: Each user is a Windows user with a probability of $10^{-4}$.  As a down and dirty approximation, you might assume that this holds independently of all the other people in your sample.  Certainly simplifies the computation.

Comment: Should note:  you are already making the simplifying assumption that "using Windows" and "going to the website" are independent.  And you are assuming that going to the website on one day is independent of going on some other day.  These may or may not be realistic assumptions, depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Yes, both your comments about independence should be assumed in the question.

Comment: @user956830 thanks for the clarification -- that makes the solution pretty straightforward, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that a user has a Windows phone is $10^{-4}$.  In a situation such as this, where there are many users and the probability of the event of interest is small, a Poisson distribution is an appropriate assumption.

The expected number of Windows users on any one day is $\lambda = 10^4 \cdot 10^{-4} = 1$.  If $X$ is the number of Windows phone users on a day, then
$$\begin{align}
P(X \ge 3) &= 1 - P(X=0) - P(X=1) - P(X=2)  \\
&= 1 - e^{-\lambda} - \frac{\lambda}{1!} e^{-\lambda} - \frac{\lambda^2}{2!} e^{-\lambda}
\end{align}$$
Having computed $P(X \ge 3)$, then the expected number of days in the year in which three or more Windows phone users visit the site is $365 \cdot P(X \ge 3)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can model the number of windows users who visit your site $W$ as a [hypergeometric random variable:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

If we imagine an urn filled with 1 million balls, of which 100 are white and 999,900 are red, then the 10000 visitors you get each day can be modeled as drawing 10000 balls from the urn *without replacement*.

This is what the hypergeometric distribution is meant to model. The probability of exactly $w$ windows users visiting on a particular day is given by:

$$P(W=w) =\frac{{100 \choose w}{999900\choose 10000-w}}{1000000\choose 10000}$$

Since you said the daily visits are independent, the number of days where you get at least 3 windows users visiting your site can be modeled as a [Binomial random variable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), where we model each day of the year as a coin flip with $P(H)=P(W\geq 3)$ and we are performing 365 flips.

The expected number of “Heads” we will get in 365 flips is simply $365P(H)=365P(W\geq3)$

All that remains is to calculate $P(W\geq3)=1-P(W<3)$ using the hypergeometric pmf I gave above.